# ¿Como puedo enviar los datos con mssql_fetch_object? -PHP en putty

Tags: php, sql, putty

Buen dia
Estoy programando en php por medio de putty y me quede estancando donde envio los datos a la tabla:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

                            <tr bgcolor="BLUE">
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>CODIGO</FONT></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>PRODUCTO</FONT></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>PRECIO</FONT></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>CUOTA</FONT></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>TOTAL</FONT></th>
                                <th bgcolor=\"#17676c\" ><FONT SIZE='1' color='white'>OPERACION</FONT></th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_object($cursor9)){ ?>
                            <tr>
                            <form action="cotizapro.php?xidvendedor=11&idcodpro=<?php echo $row->idcodpro; ?>" method="POST">

                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <? echo $row[2]; ?> </FONT></td>
                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <? echo $row[3]; ?> </FONT></td>
                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <input type="text" value="<? echo $row->precio;?>" name="precio"></FONT></td>
                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <input type="text" value="<? echo $row->cuotapro;?>" name="cuota"></FONT></td>
                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <? echo $row[5]+ $row[6]; ?> </FONT></td>
                                <td><FONT SIZE='1'> <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="submit"> </FONT></td>
                            </tr>
                                 <?php } mssql_free_result($cursor9); ?>
```

no me aparece ni un dato y supuestamente con object me permitiria hacer esa operacion $row->precio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ni un dato

No quiero utilizar mssql_fetch_array porque no me permite llamar el nombre de las columnas de la tabla a menos que utilice el numero de columna que es para llamarlo y esa no es la idea, necesito el dato para que se quede guardada en la variable y al momento de actualizar quede guardada y enviada en este mismo archivo para se actualice en esta misma pagina.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda o idea.

Comment: Estás usando índices numéricos sobre `$row` para obtener los datos, debes cambiarlos por `$row->nombreDeColumna` poniendo el nombre de la columna en cada caso.

Comment: Losé, eran una pruebas, pero el problema es mssql_fetch_object, en putty no lo lee al parecer quisiera saber si ay otra manera para marcar el objeto, o sino del $row[1] establecerlo en una variable para llamarlo despues

Comment: No entiendo qué tiene que ver esto con putty ¿? Si funciona con uno, funciona con otro. El hecho es que si usas `mssql_fetch_object` la lectura se haría así: `$row->laColumna`  y si usas `mssql_fetch_array` la lectura se haría así: `$row[indiceNumerico]` o `$row['laColumna']` En el código que expones **hay incongruencia entre el método `fetch` que usas y la forma en que lees lo datos**, como ya te señalé en mi anterior comentario. Lo que dices sobre putty y sobre una variable no entiendo qué quiere decir. Corrige la incongruencia y si no funciona entonces explica con + claridad lo que quieres.